# Flutter - Uploading Image to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to create an admin application that can select and upload an image to the Firebase storage and after that, I want the image URL to automatically reflect in the document that is sending data to the client-side application.

The only problem with this is that I only know how to upload an image to Firebase storage from the admin application. I haven't figured a way, as to how can I get the image URL into my document in Cloud Firestore.

Any suggestions or direction regarding this will be helpful.

I am using the flutter framework.

Database structure :

SkinTreatment :

```
"SkinTreatment": {
    "someDocumentName": {
      "title": "Threading",
      "packageDetails":"This package will provide you with normal upper EyeBrow Threading",
      "price" : "200"
      "duration": "75mins"
    },
    "someDocumentName2": { ... },
    "someDocumentName3": { ... }
}
```

Comment: If you post database structure

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write code to write the path and/or URL of a file in Cloud Storage to any database.  If you have a [StorageReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference-class.html) object representing a file that was uploaded, you can use its [getPath()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/getPath.html) method to get a path to the file in storage, and you can use [getDownloadUrl()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/getDownloadURL.html) to asynchronously [get a download URL](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls) as well.

For help writing data to Firestore, there is plenty of [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage).

Comment: Thank you so much for the documentation, will go through them.